# Manipulating a file - bash

Tags: bash

I need some guidance manipulating a text file that is the result of a diff. I only want those results listed after the > delimiter (which are file names) and then I will add a path to the file name for further work.
I am not dealing with large files.
I am hoping to do it all in place.

Essentially I want to take something like this

```
96a97,98
> SCR-33333.sql
> SCR-33333-WEB.sql
```

and create an action like

```
cp /add/this/path/SCR-33333.sql /to/somewhere/else
```

Can anyone please give me a quick example I can run with?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could try this, bearing in mind that it'll only work if filenames do not contains spaces...

`diff this that | awk '/^>/{print "/add/this/path/" $2}' | xargs -i cp {} /to/somewhere/else`

(note: this is a one-liner command. ignore wrapping caused by web browser.)

Comment: I don't think that particular invocation of `xargs` is going to do what is desired...

Answer (score 1):

```
grep ">" dummy.txt | cut -f 2 -d ' ' | xargs -I{} cp /add/this/path/{} somewhere
```

where 'dummy.txt' is your diff file.

Comment: It would be better to use `cut -c3-` for the `cut` part